# Implement a job queue in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, compiling, lua

I have a project depending on LuaLaTeX where the main document first generates one or more intermediate `.tex` files and then invokes `lualatex` in a loop to generate the final PDF results. This can produce up to 10-15 documents in one go. Later it may be possible that this will scale to a (web) server and produce these 10-15 documents (concretely: a musical full score plus an arbitrary number of instrumental parts) for a large number of works so we may end up with a three-digit number of `lualatex` invocations (in theory, when the project is complete and *all* scores should ever be (re)generated at once it might even reach a four-digit number.

For efficiency and for study purposes I would like to implement a multithreaded job queue for that second stage of the process where all to-be-generated documents are added to a queue and processed by a given number of worker threads (where each one launches an external process and waits for that to finish). I basically know how that works but from what I found on the net I have the suspicion that Lua doesn't provide the necessary multithreading support to do that.

So the question: does Lua (and particularly in the LuaLaTeX context) provide the machinery to reliably implement such a job queue? If so I'd be  glad about pointers.
Alternatively I would factor out the second stage to a single invocation of a Python script where I will surely find my way - but I'd actually prefer staying within the domain of the main Lua `.tex` document.

Comment: Could you make up a small example document how your document setup currently looks like? Lua has at least basic support for multi-threading which should be sufficient (keyword coroutines).

Comment: @TeXnician No, Lua has no multi-threading support.  Coroutines are a very different concept to threads.

Comment: Instead of invoking LuaLaTeX directly you could invoke it through [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) which allows you to easily run multiply shell commands in parallel.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, but it should be sufficient for the needs of this task as you do not need preemption as far as I can tell from the OP.

Comment: This (https://www.lua.org/pil/9.4.html) seems to indicate that indeed coroutines might be a solution to my task. However, I'm still not sure if I really understand the mechanics of them. What I need is one array (of file names), start a number of coroutines (?) that launch an external `lualatex` process (without blocking), and whenever one of these processes finishes the next filename from the array is passed to a new invocation of the coroutine. I have the impression that's what I can do with them, but I still have to figure out how to handle the blocking/nonblocking.

Comment: Why do you have to wait for the one coroutine to finish? Couldn't you simply start all "threads" in a loop and then let them finish when they are done (the processor won't execute more than it can take).

Comment: That would be an option, but I want to give the user the control over how many threads are started. Otherwise this would grab *all* processing resources, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 9):

Below you can find a poor man's task pool.  It makes use of the fact that `io.popen` doesn't block.  To wait for a job you can use `:close()` on its file handle.  Below is a simple example where every job just sleeps five seconds and then creates a new empty file.

```lua
local scheduled = {}
local running = {}
local jobs = {
    new = function(cmd)
        local fn = function()
            local handle = io.popen(cmd)
            table.insert(running, handle)
        end
        table.insert(scheduled, fn)
    end,
    run = function(nprogs)
        while true do
            if #scheduled == 0 then -- no more jobs?
                -- close remaining jobs and exit
                for _,job in ipairs(running) do
                    job:close()
                end
                break
            end
            if #running == nprogs then -- maximum number of jobs running?
                -- block and wait for the first one
                running[1]:close()
                table.remove(running,1)
            end
            -- start new job
            scheduled[1]()
            table.remove(scheduled,1)
        end
    end
}

jobs.new("sleep 5; touch out1")
jobs.new("sleep 5; touch out2")
jobs.new("sleep 5; touch out3")
jobs.new("sleep 5; touch out4")
jobs.new("sleep 5; touch out5")
jobs.new("sleep 5; touch out6")
jobs.new("sleep 5; touch out7")
jobs.new("sleep 5; touch out8")
jobs.new("sleep 5; touch out9")
jobs.run(4)
```

If the jobs were executed serially it would take 45 s.  I simply wait for the job on top of the stack to complete, rather than *any* job on the stack.  Hence this only gives you a good speedup if all jobs take roughly the same time (or you schedule faster jobs before slower ones).

```
$ time lua test.lua 

real    0m15.015s
user    0m0.028s
sys 0m0.011s
```